# SpriteRenderer and Image issue

Tags: image, unity-game-engine, sprite, game-development

I'm making my own game and i got some issue when i work with my image and SpriteRenderer. So the problem is that i am very limited in order in layer in SpriteRenderer because pos Z in image do almost nothing. I have 3 objects: Image that need to be on backgorund, 6 SpriteRenderer that need to be on top of first image and image that need to be on top of other objects. And that's is the problem, because when i try to change order in layer for sprites it always go on top of the third object if it's more than 1 but if it's less than 1 if goes before first object. Please give me some advice if you know what to do whith this, i'ts my first game and i realy want to release my game some day.Thanks.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]
There is the image about my issue.